# Update SQL Server table with content from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to populate the contents of a SQL Server table with the contents of another.

I have one table, `Document Items`, which contains (say) `VendorPartNumber` and `UnitCost` columns.

I then have another table, `PO Items`, with `VendorPartNumber` and `UnitCost`.

What do I need to do to get the relevant column contents from `DocumentItems` into PO Items?

Comment: What is your means of associating what [Document Item] goes to which [PO Item]?

Comment: Copy your post title, paste it in Google, and your answer is on the first page.

Answer (score 1):

```
update dbo.[PO Items]

set 
    VendorPartNumber = di.VendorPartNumber,
    UnitCost = di.UnitCost
from DocumentItems di 

where [PO Items].[{key column name}] = di.[{key column name}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is for one time operation:

If Part Oder Number is unique key in both tables, you can use the sub select statement from source table and set the values to 2nd table.

Ex:

```
update PO Items 
set VendorPartNumber = (select VendorPartNumber 
                        from Document Items 
                        where partOrdernumer = ?), 
    UnitCost = (select UnitCost 
                from Document Items 
                where partOrdernumer = ?) 
where partOrdernumer = ?
```

Else use triggers to update second table.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with:

```
insert into POItems (VendorPartNumber, UnitCost) values (select VendorPartNumber, UnitCost from DocumentItems);
```

You can add where clause if you need.